# Function notation meaning: $f: \{a,b\} \to a$ - Zorich - MA I - p18

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

I have some notation I haven't seen before:

$$f: \{a,b\} \to a\text{ and } g:\{a,b\}\to b$$

What does this mean? We are mapping from some $X=\{a,b\}$ to some $Y=a$? So pretty much we are always mapping to the first element?

I don't get why this implies $g \circ f : \{a,b\} \to b$

We first map $\{a,b\}\to a$ and then map $a \to b$? That doesn't make sense to me.

---

I feel like I have an element after $f$ and then $g$ doesn't make sense. What am I thinking about incorrectly?

Also, why are we mapping from a set, to an element?

Comment: What is the context? Are we looking at axiomatic set theory? If so, $a$ and $b$ are both sets and $\{a,b\}$ is the set containing exactly two elements: $a$ and $b$.

Comment: @Jason: No, this is from Zorich's book *Mathematical Analysis I*, and it's just a very simple example to show that composition of functions is not commutative.

Comment: Ah, gotcha. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a slightly strange notation, but from the context it is clear that he means $f(a)=f(b)=a$ and $g(a)=g(b)=b$. Then $(g \circ f)(a)=(g \circ f)(b)=b$.

Comment: That makes perfect sense, thank you. Shouldn't it be $\{a,b\}\to\{a\}$ even still? Since we normally say $f:A\to B$ where $A$ and $B$ are sets, where here $a$ isn't a set

Comment: Yes, that's why I said the notation was strange. ;-)

Comment: Thanks, that is what I thought :).

Answer (score 1):

I'd just like to expand on the discussion between Committing to a challenge and Hans Lundmark -- Zorich did point out on p5 that: "Wherever no confusion can arise we allow ourselves to denote the one-element set {a} simply as a."

Comment: I do recall that, thanks for pointing that out. That being said, I wish he didn't do that, since it is very lazy to leave it out.

Comment: I do agree. Beside, that convention being used probably "saved" less characters than what was "lost" on writing the aforementioned sentence. :)